# handy way to convert formated data to struct

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I need to convert a formated data to struct like this:

```
struct header
{ 
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
}
```

I have to do it manually like this:

```
[data getBytes:&h.a range:(NSRange){0,4}];
[data getBytes:&h.b range:(NSRange){4,4}];
[data getBytes:&h.c range:(NSRange){8,2}];
```

Is there a better way to convert the data to struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[data getBytes:&h range:(NSRange){0, sizeof(struct header)}];
```

Comment: You might run into trouble with alignment though, e.g. between versions of the compiler or processors. It's probably worth looking into `#pragma pack`; LLVM's is supposed to be exactly compatible with MSVC's if that helps with Googling.

Comment: @Tommy can you tell me in which condition (or the complier) that the trouble will happen. I tested with llvm and it seems works.

Comment: @xhan: a compiler will often insert padding bytes between struct entries, so that the individual entries align with word boundaries or to ensure that the total struct size is an integer multiple of the platform's word size or for other reasons. `#pragma pack` gives you some control over that. E.g. if if I take your struct and add an `int d` after `char c` then print the sizeof then through LLVM compiling for the iPad 5.0 simulator I get 16, with d being at an offset of 12 bytes relative to the start of the struct. If packing were tight it'd be at 9.